# Button to return changes made to a property?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, methods, properties

I am trying to the value of properties during run time. First I am trying to do it with the name property for a person but I am not sure how to complete the if statement down below. I would like it to reopen my Form2 which takes in the student as a parameter and it will display all the details for them. Any help or advice would be much appreciated. If I have done this completely wrong, please let me know give me some guidance or advice on how to edit a property data in runtime.

```
public class Student :IPerson
{
    //Method that changes the original name
    public string ChangeName(string newForename)
    {
        _forename = newForename;
        return _forename;
    }
}

public partial class Edit_Details : Form
{      
    public Edit_Details(Student student)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        nameLabel.Text = student.Forename;
        student.ChangeName(editNameTextBox.Text);
        //if(savebutton.Click) //how can I get this to replace the old name with the new one when the button is pressed??
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to wire up an event to savebutton.Click, then whenever the button gets clicked that event will fire. in this case you would want to do something like what you already have for ChangeName in the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in

```
 public Edit_Details(Student student)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        nameLabel.Text = student.Forename;
        savebutton.Click+=(sender,e)=>
          {
             savebutton.Text=student.ChangeName(editNameTextBox.Text);
          };
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much. This works great except that I used new Student(student.ChangeName(editNameTextBox.Text), instead of savebutton.Text=student.ChangeName(editNameTextBox.Text);